# iframe Scrollbar using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

can any one tell me how will i set scroll-bar to iframe through
JavaScript ??

Comment: Nice one ! In your previous question you want to remove this... And that now you want to add it... Please clarify what you want actually ?

Comment: This is alternate way to solve previous issue..so i asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow:hidden` on the stylesheet of the document inside the `iframe`. This should remove the scrollbar. But I don't believe you can set it from the parent document if the page is from another domain.